# Positioning in arrays, fstream, and char comparison

Tags: c++, arrays, char, fstream, string-comparison

I am currently trying to do an assignment in my C++ class. I think I've gotten as far as I can on my own.

The assignment calls for me to read names from a text file, put the names in order, and write them to a new file.

The names in the given text file are formatted as follows:

> Jackie   Sam   Tom   Bill   Mary   Paul   Zev   Barb   John

My code that I have for the assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string nameArray[26] = {};

int main() {

// Defined variables
int y = 65,  lineNumber = 0;
string readName;

// Opens the text file LineUp
ifstream readfile;
readfile.open("LineUp.txt");

// Opens the text file InOrder
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("InOrder.txt");

// Read name from file
while (readfile >> readName) {

    // If first character of name != char(y),
    // run loop
    while (readName[0] != char(y)) {

        y++;
        lineNumber++;

        // If first character of name = char(y),
        // add name to lineNumber's position in array
        if (readName[0] == char(y)) {
            nameArray[lineNumber] = readName;

        }
    }

    // Reset values of lineNumber and y
    y = 65;
    lineNumber = 0;
}

// Writes names in array to file
for (int x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
    outfile << nameArray[x] << endl;

// Close files
readfile.close();
outfile.close();

// Print statement so you can see at least
// something happens
cout << "KIDS ORGANIZED. BEEP. BOOP. BEEP.\n";
cin.get();
return 0; 
}
```

The output to the file made in the program that holds the ordered names:

> Barb
>
> John
>
> Mary
>
> Paul
>
> Sam
>
> Tom
>
> Zev

(It contains many more empty lines than what stack overflow shows.)

The questions I have are as follows:

1: How can I get rid of the empty spaces in the array for when I want to write the names to the text file InOrder.txt?

2: The names Jackie and Bill are not being shows because the positions in the array are being overwritten by the other two names. How can I check if those positions are filled to add in these two names?

3: Is there anything in my program I can do to make it more efficient or more readable? Or just do better in general, I guess.

A big thank you to anyone willing to try to figure out how to solve these problems!

Comment: You accessed out-of-range `nameArray[26]` in the `for` loop, which is bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by out-of-range, but when I had the array within the function, it would crash the debugger.

Comment: Use vector in place of array of string...it will automatically solve your problem of out-of-bounds

Comment: Your declaration is `string nameArray[26] = {};`, so only `nameArray[0]` to `nameArray[25]` are avaialble and you must not use `nameArray[26]`.

Comment: @Tejendra I don't know terminology well. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm not sure how that's really relevant to be honest. I changed the array limit to 50 for now, though, if that's what you were saying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the length of your string array. You only reserve 26 elements. In your for loop

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 26; x++)
    outfile << nameArray[x] << endl;
```

you try to access element 0 to 26 (that are 27 elements in total), that's more than you allocated. You have to change this loop to something like

```
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
    outfile << nameArray[x] << endl;
```

so it won't crash.
But the main problem in your program is the sorting system. As you already have noticed, as soon as two kids have a name with the same first letter, one name will be overwritten.
A better approach would be to use some of the standard libraries.
First i would not use a std::string array, but a std::vector. A vector is, simply said, a better and dynamic array with a lot more functions. If you want to know more about vectors, check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).
With a vector you can read every name first and sort it later:

```
std::vector<std::string> nameVector;
while(readfile >> readName) {
    //add name to the end of the vector
    nameVector.push_back(readName);
}
```

Now you can use [std::sort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort the vector.

```
std::sort(nameVector.begin(), nameVector.end());
```

And last write everything to your output file:

```
for(int x = 0; x < nameVector.size(); ++x)
    outfile << nameVector[x] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I haven't learned about vectors or arrays in my class yet, so I'm not surprised that I wasn't aware of a more efficient way than an array haha. 

I'll read up on how to use vectors, and will try your solution after I attempt using the previous solution I was given. Thank you!

Comment: Oh my god it worked. Not only did it work, but it greatly reduced my code. Thank you so much! Now, I understand the logic behind what is going on, I think, but I'll definitely read up more on vectors and functions within algorithm. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't use the `nameArray[26]` in the `for-loop` as it is out of range.

Secondly by now surely you must have realized the issue. You logic reserve a place for name with each alhpabet and if there are two names starting with same alphabet it creates problem. Also the blank spaces are ther because of the places in the array not having any names starting with respective alphabet. for example. no name starts with A so a blank space will be in start of the file similary no name starts with C so a blank space would be there after the name Barb.

As per your logic the solution should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Can be many names
string nameArray[100] = {};

int main() {

    // Defined variables
    int y = 65,  lineNumber = 0;
    string readName;

    // Opens the text file LineUp
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("LineUp.txt");

    // Opens the text file InOrder
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("InOrder.txt");

    //Run while the names are not checked for all alphabets
    while (y <= 90) {
        // Read names from file till the end is reached 
        while (readfile >> readName) {

            // If first character of name != char(y),
            // run loop
            if(readName[0] == char(y)) {
                // If first character of name = char(y),
                // add name to lineNumber's position in array
                nameArray[lineNumber] = readName;
                lineNumber++;
            }
            }
        }
        //Check File for next character
        y++;
    }

    // Writes names in array to file
    for (int x = 0; x < lineNumber; x++)
        outfile << nameArray[x] << endl;

    // Close files
    readfile.close();
    outfile.close();

    // Print statement so you can see at least
    // something happens
    cout << "KIDS ORGANIZED. BEEP. BOOP. BEEP.\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0; 
}
```

Note that this code works for only Upper-case letters and sorts only based on first alphabet.

Comment: I understand why there are blank spaces, yes. What I originally wanted to do was check the first letter for every name in the file for A. If any of the first letters were A, then it goes into the array. Next position in the array. Does any more equal A? No, then onto the next letter. So on and so forth. However, I do not know how to write this.. This was all I could come up with. So, I need to somehow get it to work at least.

Comment: Okay gimme a bit to modify the code you have written

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for. Your code gives me an infinite loop for some reason I believe, but if I can get this to work, then I can scrap the array idea altogether. Thank you!